# Rails: Restrict specific user roles from editing/deleting specific records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am looking to restrict a certain user role from editing specific records in the database.

For example I have items records 1,2,3,4 and 5 in my Item table.

I want to give editing/deleting access for items 1 and 2 for user1, but restrict user1 from editing/deleting items 3,4, and 5.

Is there a gem or a specific way one would achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

cancan is your choice ! which currently many use it https://github.com/ryanb/cancan and most updated

for example:

```
 <% if can? :update, @article %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: From my understanding, CanCan only restricts users from controller actions of a specific model, not specific records in a model.

Comment: i thik there shld be a way,like when u looping your items, just check if can? your custom action to perform ur task. https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Custom-Actions